# Stock return based on percentage

Tags: stocks, stock-markets, capital-gain, capital-loss

If you were to buy $1000 dollars worth of shares, and the worth went up 60% and you sold, would you earn $600 or $1600? When you sell, do you keep your original capital, ($1000)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> would you earn $600 or $1600?

You would **have** $1600, and your **earnings** would be $600.

That's the only answer it could be, since if you start with $1000 from your savings, then it's impossible for you to have *also* earned that money in the stock market.

> When you sell, do you keep your original capital, ($1000)?

If you own a car which you bought for $1000, and then sell it for $1600, do you keep the original $1000?

Comment: "earnings" doesn't seem like the right word here, because it has a specific meaning in finance and tax consequences.  "gain" is a word often used with stocks, and "profit" or "income" could fit as well.

Comment: Thank for the help. I'm relatively new to investing, and I've been trying to look around for help everywhere I can.